# Force the password expiration date for a LOCAL user account

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to force the specific expiration date of a password NOT an account for a LOCAL user NOT an AD user using powershell.

I know you can do this with an AD user, by using ADSI/LDAP and setting the pwdLastSet attribute to 0.

Can a similar thing be done for local accounts, if so, using what command/syntax. I have looked all over google, and played with net user commands, and I have managed to make the local user account expire, however, I dont want the account to expire, I want the password to expire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to set an account expiration date is to use the [`net`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771865.aspx) command:

```
& net user $username /expires:"$($date.ToString('MM\/dd\/yyyy'))"
```

AFAIK password expiration of local users can't be set to a specific date or for individual accounts. The expiration is controlled by the [Maximum Password Age](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994573.aspx) (local) security policy. You can set the maximum age from the commandline like this:

```
& net accounts /maxpwage:$numdays
```

but the policy affects all local accounts, and just defines a maximum age, not a specific expiration date.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but as I mentioned in my OP I was talking about making the password expire NOT the account. It seems like it is two different things, and as I also mentioned in my post, I already figured out how to expire the account using the net user command you mentioned above. Sorry I didnt make it more clear in my OP. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, your question is quite clear. I just didn't read carefully enough. Sorry. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, based on your hunch I did confirm that these properties are ONLY available through AD accounts, and not local accounts, so it looks like there is no way to do what I am trying to do. Not sure why some dipsh*t down voted my question as I thouroughly researched it, clearly stated it, and there is not a lot of information on the internet in regards to windows local user accounts in general, 99% of the information is on AD accounts. So hopefully someone else finds this question useful. Thanks again for your contribution!

Comment: I wasn't the one downvoting, but an argument could be made that your question would be more suitable for [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) or even [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) than it is for SO, since it's not really a programming topic.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to force password expiration, just so that you force the user to change the password on the next logon, you can also do it with the net command using:

```
net user $username /logonpasswordchg:yes
```